# How to inject a NOOP into a dissassembled C# program

Tags: c#, .net

TL;DR;

I need to inject a few NOOPs into a c# executable to prove a point. I don't have the source.

I was recently wondering if a PS3 emulator existed. There are several sites claiming that one exists, but basically they are all scamware and redirect you to an add page, telling you that you need to fill out special offers to download things.

Below is a segment of the code disassembled with ILDisassem from Visual Studio 2010.
Basically, if you hit "yes" it opens a web browser to the spam link below. if you hit anything else, the app closes.

```
.method private instance void  Form1_Load(object sender,
                                          class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs e) cil managed noinlining nooptimization
{
  // Code size       91 (0x5b)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init (valuetype [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxResult V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4     0x3e8
  IL_0005:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Thread::Sleep(int32)
  IL_000a:  ldstr      "New Version of PS3 Emulator is Available , Would Y"
  + "ou Like to Download it Now \? "
  IL_000f:  ldc.i4.s   68
  IL_0011:  ldstr      "Version 1.9.6 Available"
  IL_0016:  call       valuetype [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxResult [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction::MsgBox(object,
                                                                                                                                                            valuetype [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle,
                                                                                                                                                            object)
  IL_001b:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_001c:  sub
  IL_001d:  switch     ( 
                        IL_0055,
                        IL_005a,
                        IL_005a,
                        IL_005a,
                        IL_003c,
                        IL_004e)
  IL_003a:  br.s       IL_005a
  IL_003c:  ldstr      "http://www.fileice.net/download.php\?file=3xi3w"
  IL_0041:  call       class [System]System.Diagnostics.Process [System]System.Diagnostics.Process::Start(string)
  IL_0046:  pop
  IL_0047:  call       void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::EndApp()
  IL_004c:  br.s       IL_005a
  IL_004e:  call       void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::EndApp()
  IL_0053:  br.s       IL_005a
  IL_0055:  call       void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::EndApp()
  IL_005a:  ret
} // end of method Form1::Form1_Load
```

My question is, How can I replace the `EndApp()` lines with Noops?

Comment: Is the goal to inject into it? Or to just change functionality? If the latter.. you have the IL... change it and build it.

Comment: My goal is to change the functionality. How do I "change and build" those lines? I don't have the source.

Comment: Change the functionality of the existing executable? You do have the source.. you're looking at the IL. Build it with ILAsm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)/[JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) + [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/). It'll handle the whole decompilation and recompilation for you.

You could also use [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [ilasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to decompile the code, change it with your favorite editor, and recompile it again. This may cause some issues if the il code is obfuscated where ildasm may refuse to work with it ([SupressIldasmAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/SV-SE/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.suppressildasmattribute%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), or non-compilable code may be generated (odd variable/method names, etc...)

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure how to build it. Loading the Visual Studios environemnt in a command prompt put ilasm in the path. Rocking the file with vim then runing ilasm worked as you described. Thank you for teach me about this.

Answer (score 1):

IL is not like machine code where you have to overwrite instructions with nops. It's basically source code that will need to be compiled and built again. So basically you don't have to noop anything just delete the EndApp() lines and rebuild.

Comment: So my failing was that I didn't know how to edit the IL because windows "beeped" when I tried to delete lines. I dumped the IL to a file, rocked it with vim, then ran ilasm. Sadly, I can only accept once answer and @Simon Svensson gave me a little more to go on. Answer Up Voted.